# An inequality concerning derivative of any order at $0$ for an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on the unit disk , $f(0)=0$ , and $|f(z)|\le M , \forall z \in \mathbb C$ , then how may we show that $|f^{(n)} (0)| \le Mn! , \forall n \in \mathbb N $ ?

Comment: Apparently, you means that "$\lvert\,f(z)\rvert\le M$, for all $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert< 1$." - Otherwise, assuming that this holds for all $z\in\mathbb Z$, you get that $f^{(n)}(z)=0$, for all $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the following Cauchy formula: $$f^{(n)} (z) =\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r} \frac{f(\xi )}{(\xi -z)^{n+1} } d\xi $$ hence $$f^{(n)} (0) =\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r} \frac{f(\xi )}{\xi^{n+1} } d\xi $$ therefore
$$|f^{(n)} (0)| \leq\frac{n!}{2\pi }\cdot \frac{M}{r^{n+1}}\cdot 2\pi =\frac{Mn!}{r^{n+1}} .$$

Now letting $r\to 1 $ we obtain $$|f^{(n)} (0)| \leq  Mn! .$$